# useState not updating displays on first click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a table, whose rows can be clicked. Once clicked, they should load an objects values in to some inputs `.value` fields. It does do this, but only once the same table row has been clicked twice.

Here's some images explaining it:

Page is loaded:
[image: Image showing the page when loaded]

Then, after clicking the middle record:
[image: Image showing the error]

Then, after clicking the same record again:
[image: Image showing the correct information, only after the second mouse click]

I use a useState to track all of the characters key:value pairs and another to track all of the display fields. But I'm not sure how to stop this error from happening.

Here's the code for my onClick function, attached to each table row:

```
function barkCharData(idIn){

    //set the st_charData state to contain whatever character was selected
    set_st_charData({
        id: ar_charBin[idIn-1].id,
        fName: ar_charBin[idIn-1].first_name,
        sName: ar_charBin[idIn-1].second_name,
        age: ar_charBin[idIn-1].age,
        gender: ar_charBin[idIn-1].gender,
        race: ar_charBin[idIn-1].race,
        classType:ar_charBin[idIn-1].classType,
        level: ar_charBin[idIn-1].level
    })

    console.log("After init, st_charData.id = "+st_charData.id)

    //then set st_boxes to be referenced
    set_st_displayBoxes({
        box_id: document.getElementById("txt_idField"),
        box_fName: document.getElementById("txt_fNameField"),
        box_sName: document.getElementById("txt_sNameField"),
        box_age: document.getElementById("txt_ageField"),
        box_gender: document.getElementById("txt_genderField"),
        box_race: document.getElementById("txt_raceField"),
        box_class: document.getElementById("txt_classField"),
        box_level: document.getElementById("txt_levelField"),
    })

    try{
        //From usestates, updated above,
        //assign the char data to the relevant box
        st_displayBoxes.box_id.value = st_charData.id
        st_displayBoxes.box_fName.value = st_charData.fName;
        st_displayBoxes.box_sName.value = st_charData.sName;
        st_displayBoxes.box_age.value = st_charData.age;
        st_displayBoxes.box_gender.value = st_charData.gender;
        st_displayBoxes.box_race.value = st_charData.race;
        st_displayBoxes.box_class.value = st_charData.classType;
        st_displayBoxes.box_level.value = st_charData.level;
     }
    
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log("\n\nPants were shat in:\n\t'barkCharData' function:\n" +e)
    }                    
}
```

And here's the code for an onChange handler which is attached to each of the text boxes:

```
    {
        try{
            console.log("Fired the change event");
            
            //update the useState with the change
            set_st_charData({ ...st_charData, [e.target.name]: [e.target.value] });
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log("Bowel movement detected in 'displayChangeHandler': "+error);
        }
    }
```

I know that the `st_charData` useState is initially empty before it's updated which I think is what's causing my issue. Problem is, I don't know how to work around it. Have tried looking at other answers but haven't managed to solve it.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Can you try assigning it to a variable in local scope and then putting it there ? Might work as well.

Comment: The `set_st_charData` method is asyn, so you cannot use the "new" values. You will need to use them in the next render. The same applies to the `set_st_displayBoxes` and is the reason you needed to use the `try/catch` code below, due to the `st_displayBoxesz` not having been set. Last, you should not be using DOM manipulations through React. Try to specify the values when you render the form elements.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Ok, how do I use them in the next render? Sorry, sort of new to react. Also, why shouldn't I use DOM manipulations?

Answer (score 0):

Gave myself tunnel vision on this one. Turned out to be quite straightforward, thanks to @GabrielePetroli for mentioning `useEffect`.

You can use the `useEffect` hook to fire code every time there's a re-render. You can also have the `useEffect` track a particular `useState` and re-render whenever that particular one changes.

```
useEffect(() => 
    { 
        //code you want to run each re-render
        //...like updating displays
    }, [<useState>,<something else>]);
```

By adding in things you want to track as a dependency in the array above, you'll force this `useEffect` to fire whenever the value changes and updating it in the new render.

The solution to my problem was to perform all of my assignments (updating useState with a newly clicked character record) in my `onClick` function and then having my `useEffect` paste the relevant info in to the inputs during re-renders.